# Developing PHP Custom Application Setup Environment

Tags: php, installation

I Have Created PHP Custom Application, want to make a UI for Setup the project in User System without touching and configuring the code.

As of Now, I am Calling a Php File Writing the complete Script(DB creation, and table Creation, Loading the Content in Table, creating Config File etc.)
It`s Working File. if there is an other solution please Share.

Thanks.

Comment: What would be result of running installation script?

Comment: @Thamilan, i want to take the DB Credentials, and Run DB script for creating and populating the Data. Example as like `opencart.`

Comment: Better, check if the table exists or data exists in DB, if not run the installation script otherwise your regular process.

Comment: Yes i can do that, my problem is i am running the application from `index.php` and installation also from php; i don't want call installation directory for every time. do you have any solution.?

Comment: Just check if DB exists separately (1 line of code), if yes proceed, otherwise redirect to installation script

Comment: Thanks, Will Proceed with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the installation, create a particular file.

In the index.php, check if this file exists before proceeding.  If it does, installation has been run before and you can proceed.  If it doesn't, the application is not installed yet.

Comment: creating file will increase the file fystem, i don't want to do that, create your own logic with existed resources, as @Thamilan said use DB and write logic.

Comment: What does "increase the file system" mean?  You mean it would take up too much space?  It could be a zero-byte file.  Or do you mean it'd take too long?  The time it takes would be infinitesimally small compared to the much slower operation of creating a database connection and getting a response from a database server.

Comment: Yes, True, will try to do that. Thanks

Comment: Another problem with checking the database for this is that if the database ever goes down or is restarted for some reason, your code may assume that the application hasn't been installed and production users may see an installation prompt.  You'd need to somehow distinguish between a missing database connection because the application has not been installed yet, or a missing database connection because the database is temporarily down.  Ultimately you'd still need some separate file (eg. a file containing database configuration) as ultimate arbitar of whether the application is installed.